# Azure Web App: Sometimes IIS rewrite rules don't work on one instance

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a web app with Standard service plan with ARRAfinity enabled. So each client is stick on particular instance. The web app has some IIS rewrite rules defined in web.config. 
The problem that sometimes these rules stop working on one particular instance. After resetting ARRAfinity cookies(i.e. requests go to another instance) or web app restart everything starts working well. 
We don't have any particular steps how to reproduce...

May be someone noticed the same with Azure Web App and IIS rewrite rules?

Comment: Could you share your IIS rewrite rules?

Comment: <rule name="ObjectStorage ReverseProxy" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="ObjectStorage/(ne|je|cus|st|au)/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://objects{R:1}.blob.core.windows.net/objects/{ToLower:{R:2}}" />
        </rule>

Comment: I tested the similar issue for a couple of days, it could work on my side. I assumed that you could create an Azure support request for this issue, for more details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: Thanks Bruce. sometimes it's reproduced. Support team didn't find anything  except abnormal memory consumption at that time. may be it is related somehow....

Comment: @Ilya have you figured it out? I have the same issue.

Comment: @cryss, Nope Fortunately it happens not so often... so we have to live with that :)